# Error when start activity from a module

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I have a fully working application / module in Android studio called `appone` with default activity `com.company.appone.view.SplashActivity`

Now, I want to create another module `apptwo` that will start default activity of `appone` aka   `com.company.appone.view.SplashActivity` on launch.

But when trying to define new activity on `apptwo` I got error `Activity not found`, you can see red text in this [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsZTs.png)

This my `apptwo` files

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':appone')
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsZTs.png)

Can some one please let me know why the **`appone..SplashActivity`** is not recognized in **`apptwo`** manifest file?